How does one make a one dimensional plot, i.e., there is no Plot1D command
Suppose one wants to make a plot that shows how one plots a variable and a transform of that variable on a single line. Suppose that line is horizontal, and the top scale would be some variable, lets say $x$, and the bottom variable would be some transform of $x$, let's say $\frac{x}{1+x}$, where the ticks and numbers on the top of the line would be typical values of $x$, and the ticks and numbers on the bottom of the line would be nice numbers and ticks for $\frac{x}{1+x}$ that correspond to the original $x$ values above that line. Such displays are common in the older medical literature but have recently become less popular, perhaps because slide rules are no longer commonly used.
There is no Plot1D command in Mathematica. So, how can this be done in Mathematica? Is there some way to trick the software into doing this?
EDIT: For example, can the following be collapsed so there is no $y$-axis:

Edit: For example, I took the image above and transformed it graphically using Gimp.

Now, how does one do that in Mathematica?

Why not use the Plot commands? something like Plot[x/(1+x),{x,0,10}] Such displays are common in the older medical literature then it will help to include a link to such an image or paste it in your question. As they say, a picture is worth a thousand words :).   Mathematica is the best software for plotting, so I am sure whatever it is, it could be done in Mathematica.

@Nasser I could look around for one, but the image I inserted should explain what I want. Obviously, I could reverse the direction of the ticks. The question is, how to plot something with a zero or infinite aspect ratio?

I suggest you look at AxisObject.

@lericr I looked at it. It's close but the AxisObject's only specify a single number range for each one. If they could be sandwiched together or placed back to back that might solve the problem. Any ideas on how to do that?

i would think that would be easy to do. you can specify endpoints and you can combine graphics. sorry i can’t experiment right now, but it really seems like it should be rather straightforward. i’m sure it would take time to fiddle around an get it working, but conceptually it doesn’t seem intractable. i hope someone else can jump in.

@lericr Lucky for me, Michael E2 jumped in, and provided an answer that I patched up to make perfect. Can you approve my edits, please?

Here's an idea:
Graphics[{}, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{None, None}, {
    Join[Table[{x, x, {0., 0.01`}}, {x, Range[0.95, 1., 0.01]}], 
     Table[{x, , {0., 0.005`}}, {x, Range[0.95, 1., 0.002]}]],
    Join[
     Table[If[
       y === Infinity, {1.`, Infinity, {0., 0.01`}}, {y/(1+y), 
        y, {0., 0.01`}}], {y, {20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 200, 
        Infinity}}], 
     Table[{y/(1+y), 
       Spacer[{0, 0}], {0., 0.005`}}, {y, {25, 35, 45, 55, 64, 80, 
        120, 140, 160, 180, 250, 300, 350, 400}}]]}},
 PlotRange -> {{0.95, 1.}, {0., 0.0001}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]



Almost perfect, just needs better ticks. Congratulations and thank-you. (+1).

@Carl Oops, I first did it with a small gap, so you could see the ticks. Then I saw you wanted the frame really flattened, but I forgot about the ticks.

P.S. The inverse of $s=\frac{t}{1+t}$ is $t=\frac{s}{1-s}$, where $t$ is time and $s$ is transformed time on a 0 to 1 scale. BTW, these are the same transforms that are used to convert between the beta prime distribution and the beta distribution. Such a transform allows for plotting a curve of infinite duration on a 0 to 1 scale and allows visualization of "terminal" curve behaviour, a question of much interest in many fields, so the question is far from arbitrary. I can take your code and fix it easily enough.... Thanks again.

Made some minor edits, is fixed now, perfect! For some strange reason, I am not a trusted user so it is pending.

Now completed. Thanks to an anonymous Trusted colleague.

@Carl Ah, thanks, I see. I thought any old transformation would do. I have trouble with signs and term order when transferring info from one app to another. I prefer copy-paste, but that wasn't possible here. And I didn't grok that $x$ in the original changed to $s$ and $t$, so the previous comment flew right over my head. :)

@Carl Various tasks, like editing someone else's post, posting comments on others' posts, up/down votes, and so on require different levels of rep points to perform. That's the meaning of "trusted." For editing I think you earn 2 points for each approved edit until you become a "trusted user" for editing, which is either at 1000 pts or 2000 pts (I forget). It's explained somewhere in the help docs for SE.

I have a 13k rep on cross validated so being NOT trusted here is silly. That suggests that StackExchange is as one dimensional as the plot type requested here.

Here is a method using AxisObject's:
tLabMaj = {20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100, 200, Infinity};
tPosMaj = Table[Limit[x/(1.0 + x), x -> t], {t, tLabMaj}];
tLabMin = {25, 35, 45, 55, 64, 80, 120, 140, 160, 180, 250, 300, 350, 400};
tPosMin = Table[t/(1.0 + t), {t, tLabMin}];
Graphics[{
  AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0, {0.95, 1}}, TickDirection -> Up,
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip", TickPositions -> {{tPosMaj}, {tPosMin}}, 
    TickLabels -> {tLabMaj}, TicksStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold],
    AxisLabel -> Placed[Style["t (time)", Red], Center]],
  AxisObject[{"Horizontal", 0, {0.95, 1}}, TickDirection -> Down,
    TickLabelPositioning -> "Tip", TickPositions -> {{0.95, 1, 0.01},
      {0.95, 1, 0.002}},
    TicksStyle -> Directive[Bold],
    AxisLabel -> "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(t\), \(1 + t\)]\)"]},
  PlotRange -> {{0.95, 1}, {0.0, 0.001}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> Large]



Very nice, I like it. (+1)
